# Getting warnings while Using a user defined function in ddply/transform, mutate for a large dataset

Tags: r, plyr

I have a data.frame of around 200,000 rows with some date fields. I need to add a new column to the data frame which will have Fiscal Year value corresponding to the given date. A fiscal year spans parts of 2 years. In my case, it is Apr to March. A date of Mar 1, 2010 will fall into FY of 2009-10 where as July 1, 2010 will fall into 2010-11. I have coded a scalar function to do this conversion. Here is the code for these functions:

```
convMonthYearToFY = function(m, y){
  yn = y+1
  yp = y-1

  if (m < 4){
    fy = sprintf("%d-%02d", yp, y%%100)
  } else {
    fy = sprintf("%d-%02d", y, yn%%100)
  }
  return(fy)
}

convDateToFY = function(dt){
  y = 1900+as.POSIXlt(dt)$year
  m = 1+as.POSIXlt(dt)$mon
  return(convMonthYearToFY(m, y))
}
```

I am using ddply/transform to create the new column as

```
new_df = ddply(df, 1, transform, fy=convDateToFY(somedate))
```

I see the following behavior. Since df has 200,000 rows, it is very slow. second it spews the following warning messages

```
38: In if (m < 4) { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
39: In if (m < 4) { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
40: In if (m < 4) { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
41: In if (m < 4) { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I tried to use mutate and it also gives me a lots of warning messages as above. These warnings are bothersome as I can't possibly see where things may be going wrong.

What will be the best and fastest way I can achieve this transformation without any warning? For sample data, below is a data frame of two rows and the behavior of ddply and mutate:

```
df = data.frame(somedate = as.Date(c("2010-01-01", "2010-07-01"), "%Y-%m-%d"))

> ddply(df, 1, transform, fy=convDateToFY(somedate))
    somedate      fy
1 2010-01-01 2009-10
2 2010-07-01 2010-11
```

Output is Correct here...

> mutate(df, fy=convDateToFY(somedate))
>       somedate      fy
>   1 2010-01-01 2009-10
>   2 2010-07-01 2009-10
>   Warning message:
>   In if (m < 4) { :
>     the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

In case of mutate the output is WRONG.

In short, I am trying to use a user defined function in ddply/transform and mutate for a large dataset, but not having success. Please help.

regards

K

Comment: Output of mutate is garbled. The correct output is

Comment: > mutate(df, fy=convDateToFY(somedate))
    somedate      fy
1 2010-01-01 2009-10
2 2010-07-01 2009-10
Warning message:
In if (m < 4) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: The problem is that `convMonthYearToFY` is not vectorized and `transform` expects a vectorized function. Use `ifelse` instead of `if` and `else`. I also strongly suspect that there is already some package that has function for transformation from and to fiscal year. Furthermore, you are using `ddply` in a very strange way, which explains the slowness. It is designed to do operations by group. It doesn't make sense to use it with group=1 and of course it is not necessary for your task at all.

Comment: And didn't I show you the awesomeness of data.table earlier today? Why don't you use it? It's often much faster than plyr, especially for really large data (which you have not).

Comment: @Roland, I need to apply the `convMonthYearToFY` function to every row of the data table, hence usage of 1 to get around the notion of grouping. This is because I have multiple rows with the same date value and each one of them needs respective fiscal year value. I also appreciate you showing me the awesomeness of data.table. I have to get going on it. As of now I am running against a deadline and bunch of code is using ddply and ggplot2 heavily. It will be a while to replace most of ddply related code with that of data.table. I will be there soon as it is smart to use the good thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested

```
mydata$yn<- mydata$y+1
mydata$yp<- mydata$y-1
mydata$fy<-with(mydata,ifelse (m < 4), sprintf("%d-%02d", yp, y%%100),sprintf("%d-%02d", y, yn%%100))
```

Comment: This is incredible, Awesome way to achieve something which caused me long heartburn. It sure will be in my R tool chest. I tested the solution provided by you. needed a ( after ifelse (no big deal). Sorry for the delay in response. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Not a problem!